# Magento frontend is breaks and shows correctly magento 2.4.2

Tags: magento2, frontend, magento2.4, design, parent-child-theme

After I set up the **production mode** my store is working correctly, but sometimes at the page load design get's broken and loading correctly how to fix it Magento 2.4.2. I had run the below commands. I had added the flow of page-load in the screens 1,2,3 steps

1. setup:upgrade
2. setup:di:compile
3. setup:static-content:deploy
4. C:f

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Try below command from root directory via ssh**

```
 php bin/magento config:set dev/css/use_css_critical_path 0
 php bin/magento cache:clear
 php bin/magento cache:flush
```

**now run your website in private window**

Comment: Gohil Thanks for your reply can you tell why it is appearing like, by running this cmd what will happend

Comment: may be you have enabled critical css. it will load css after page load

Comment: have you tried above solution?

Answer (score 0):

It could be a directory permission error. Check your browser console and you server log.

The command line user might be able to access the directory and deploy static content but php-fpm might not have enough access.
Check the php-fpm user in your php-fpm configuration.

I hope t helps